# Access denied to resource: type=<jms>, application=JMSModule, destinationType=queue, resource=test, action=receive

Tags: jms, weblogic

I'm try to receive a weblogic server jms in spring boot . But I have encountered this problem after launch application successfully.

```
[]org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer:handleListenerSetupFailure(892): Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'jms/test' - trying to recover. Cause: Access denied to resource: type=<jms>, application=JMSModule, destinationType=queue, resource=ns-alert-test, action=receive
```

And I found it can be connect successfully in thread of [main] when launching.
It looks like the username and password is missed when thread changed

```
[main] org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean:lookup(112): Located object with JNDI name [jms/rtsConnectionFactory]
```

And I'm try to use wlfullclient.jar and wlclient.jar and wlthint3client.jar in my project . But the problem still exists. Can you give me some suggest of this problem . Below is my code 
Config:

```
@Autowired
private JmsErrorHandler jmsErrorHandler;

@Autowired
private JMSPropertiesConfig jmsPropertiesConfig;

@Bean
public JndiTemplate jndiTemplate(){
    JndiTemplate jndiTemplate =new JndiTemplate();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    properties.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", jmsPropertiesConfig.getUrl());
   if(jmsPropertiesConfig.getUname()!=null){
        properties.setProperty("username", jmsPropertiesConfig.getUname());
    }
    if(jmsPropertiesConfig.getUcert()!=null){
        properties.setProperty("password", jmsPropertiesConfig.getUcert());
    }
    jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(properties);
    return jndiTemplate;
}

@Bean
public JndiDestinationResolver jmsDestionationProvider() {
    JndiDestinationResolver destinationResolver = new JndiDestinationResolver();
    destinationResolver.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
    return destinationResolver;
}

@Bean
public JndiObjectFactoryBean connectionFactory(){
    JndiObjectFactoryBean cf = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    cf.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
    cf.setJndiName(jmsPropertiesConfig.getFactory());
    return cf;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory) connectionFactory().getObject());
    template.setSessionAcknowledgeModeName("AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE");
    template.setSessionTransacted(true);
    template.setDestinationResolver(jmsDestionationProvider());
    return template;
}

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory) connectionFactory().getObject());
    factory.setDestinationResolver(jmsDestionationProvider());
    factory.setErrorHandler(jmsErrorHandler);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(0);
    return factory;
}
```

Receive:

```
 @JmsListener(destination = "jms/test")
public void receiveApplicationNotification(String input) throws Exception {
    log.info("Receiving message from jms.external.ExampleQueue.queue "+input);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in Weblogic.

Can you please try applying below patch..

Bug 22550927 - WEBLOGIC JMS CONNECTION IS NOT THREAD-SAFE

Comment: Sorry , I can not found the patch  , can you please provider a link of 22550927 to me ? Thanks a lot

Comment: What version you are in.. below is the link for WLS12.1.2 https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchDetail?requestId=20747496&_afrLoop=424123670355329&patchId=22550927&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=oubhybq46_73